# How do I bind IsEnabled property of ContextMenu in Silverlight 4?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, binding, contextmenu

How do I bind `IsEnabled` property in Silverlight 4 (XAML)?

I tried simply `IsEnabled="{Binding ABC}"` but this is not working - the `MenuItem` is always enabled.

Thanks in advance for the clues!

Cheers

Edit:

What is interesting, when setting `Mode=TwoWay` the bindings seem to work. However, the look of context menu is updated after moving the mouse over a menu item. Is that working asynchronously? What is the way to update the layout of my context menu just after right-clicking? (I tries `UpdateLayout()` but it didn't work)

Comment: What is ABC, is it a property in the view model or are you trying to bind to something else.  If it is in the view model where are you changing ABC and notifying the view?

Comment: @Wes, Yes, that is exactly how you have written.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, it is a known bug in Silverlight Toolkit - the look of context menu does not change even if `IsEnabled` property is bound and notified properly. I had to implement a workaround (simple updating the view of the control). Anyway, thanks for the replies :)

Comment: I have the same problem - how do you update the view of the control?

Comment: ok, contextMenu1.InvalidateArrange() worked in the opened event of the context menu

Answer (score 1):

A good way to debug this is to take a look at the Output Window while debugging with Visual Studio. Problems with bindings are printed there.

Have you set your DataContext to an object that has a public property `ABC`?

Comment: I noticed, that when I set the mode (TwoWay), the binding seems to work. However, the look of a menu item does not change (until I move the cursor over it). Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Is the property in the view model a dependency property or do you implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your view model? i.e. How are you notifying the view when IsEnabled changes?

Comment: I implemented INotifyPropertyChanged.